# I have two users on Ubuntu system. for 1 user ~./profile file wrong command How to change?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I have two users on Ubuntu system. By mistake i have changed for a user his `~./profile` file. I kept wrong command in this file. As a result when I login to this user it is going for loop. How can I modify the content of this file?

Answer (score 0):

The ~ refers to the home folder of the current user. You can access directly the file in the user home folder :

```
/home/user1/.profile
/home/user2/.profile
```